# Почему при повторном проходе по массиву выводит только последний элемент массива. java

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ShuffleArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr=new int[100]; //создаем новый массив

    Random rnd = new Random();//заполняем его случайными числами
    for (int i: arr){    
      arr[i]= rnd.nextInt(100);
      System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); //выводим результат
    }

    System.out.println(" "); //перевод строки

    for (int i: arr){  //выводим еще раз
      System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
    }
  }
}
```

вывод:

> 91 65 94 21 14 3 26 74 96 21 15 61 7 46 75 39 55 67 95 77 15 50 13 49
>   53 18 37 88 29 32 57 41 64 97 85 71 50 86 93 20 57 24 8 18 21 18 60 67
>   58 69 47 33 21 3 72 1 87 44 44 32 7 21 6 52 87 40 78 32 43 65 50 63 14
>   70 17 92 58 5 54 56 34 16 1 54 2 48 17 7 60 72 66 90 26 24 42 21 73 84
>   55 30   0 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
>   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
>   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
>   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
>   30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если работаешь с foreach, то там для работы с элемента массива надо брать `i`, а не `arr[i]`

`foreach` у тебя работает по такой логике - возми каждый элемент массива `arr`, присвой его значение `i`

---

Лучше всего написать вначале нормальный цикл заполнения массива с использованием такого - `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`, а для вывода уже можно использовать `for (int i : arr)`

В итоге программа выглядит так:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ShuffleArray {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = new int[100]; //создаем новый массив

    Random rnd = new Random();//заполняем его случайными числами

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            arr[i] = rnd.nextInt(100);
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`(int i: arr)` - это поочередное присваивание всех элементов массива `arr` переменной `i`, а `arr[i]` - получение элемента массива `arr` с индексом `i` (в твоём примере - 91)

Поэтому нужно так:

```
for (int i: arr) {
  System.out.print(i+ " ");
}
```

либо так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) { 
  System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
```